# Given a circle, construct three circles tangent to it and tangent to each other

Tags: geometry, solution-verification, proof-writing, euclidean-geometry, geometric-construction

> Given a circle, construct three circles tangent to it and tangent to each other.

Surprisingly, I can find no reference to this (although there are many similar sounding problems, and Apollonius' Problem, none of which solve this.)

My solution is below.  I request verification, improvements to the exposition, or alternate solutions.  In particular, the construction has many moving parts, and I struggled to simplify it.  Is there a simpler construction, or a simpler way of writing this one?

---

**Construction:** Circumscribe a [*added:* equilateral] triangle $\triangle ABC$ around given circle $\bigcirc O$.  Label the midpoint of $AB$ as $P$, of $BC$ as $Q$, and of $CA$ as $R$.  By symmetry, these midpoints are the three points of tangency between $\triangle ABC$ and $\bigcirc O$.

Construct the bisector of $\angle  PAO$ as ray $A_p$, and the bisector of $\angle PBO$ as ray $B_p$.  Likewise construct bisector rays $B_q, C_q, C_r, A_r$.  Let $A_p$ and $B_p$ intersect at point $p$, rays $B_q$ and $C_q$ at point $q$, and $C_r$ and $A_r$ at $r$.  (See figure.  For simplicity, only some objects are shown, with the others following the same scheme.)

[image]

Now draw circles $\omega_p, \omega_q, \omega_q$ with centers $p, q, r$ respectively, each tangent to $\bigcirc O$ at $P,Q,R$ respectively.   We will show that $\omega_p, \omega_q, \omega_r$ are tangent to each other.

The reflection of ray $AB$ over ray $A_p$ is ray $AO$.  Therefore, since $AB$ is tangent to $\omega_p$, so is $AO$.  By a similar argument, $AO$ is tangent to $\omega_r$ as well.  By symmetry, these two points of tangency must be equidistant from $O$ and therefore coincide, showing that $\omega_p$ and $\omega_r$ are tangent to each other along $AO$.  A similar argument works for each pair of circles, completing the proof.

---

## Update

*Based on @aschepler's suggestion, I rewrote the solution, which I think is clearer, more succinct, and more insightful.  Further feedback is appreciated.*

Circumscribe an equilateral triangle $\triangle ABC$ around the given circle $\bigcirc O$.  Construct $\omega_{abo}, \omega_{bco}, \omega_{cao}$ as the incircles of $\triangle ABO, \triangle BCO,$ and $\triangle CAO$ respectively.  These circles are the required circles, tangent to each other and to $\bigcirc O$, as we now show.

Recall that  the incircle of an isosceles triangle is tangent to the midpoint of its base.  Therefore, $\omega_{abo}, \omega_{bco}, \omega_{cao}$ are tangent to the midpoints of $AB, BC, CA$ respectively.  For the same reason, $\bigcirc O$ is tangent to each of these same points.

Likewise, both $\omega_{abo}$ and $\omega_{cao}$ are tangent to $AO$.  By symmetry, these two points of tangency must be equidistant from $O$ and therefore coincide, showing that $\omega_{abo}$ and $\omega_{cao}$ are tangent to each other.  A similar argument works for each pair of circles, completing the proof.

Comment: @CalvinLin Yes, $ABC$ must be equilateral, thank you for that.  I could not find anything else special about the circles or a more direct property of their centers; finding such is essentially what the OP is asking.   What do you suggest?

Comment: FWIW The question is interesting when $P, Q, R$ are arbitrary points on the circle. In which case, my suggestion is to apply Inversion (assuming you're familiar with that concept), and the result should be obvious.

Comment: @CalvinLin I don't think it's possible for all three circles to be tangent to each other for arbitrary $P,Q,R$! If you disagree, please demonstrate.

Comment: We invert about $P$. The circles containing $P$ invert to become parallel lines. The inverted circles containing $Q, R$ are contained within these parallel lines, hence  have the same radius equal to $|Q'R'|/2$. This then gives us the line for the $P$ circle. Invert back to the original diagram.

Comment: Apollonius's Problem **does** solve this problem. Starting with your circle $O$ and put two other arbitrary circles $M, N$ in the plane. Use Apollonius to construct circle $p$ tangent to $O,M,N,$ then construct circle $q$ tangent to $O,p,M,$ and finally construct circle $r$ tangent to $O,p,q.$ You now have three circles tangent to $O$ and to each other. You may have trouble finding a discussion of your problem because it is simply too easy to be interesting.

Comment: If  you add a requirement that the three constructed circles must be congruent and inside the original circle then you get this construction and Apollonius no longer solves the problem. You could also try three congruent circles outside the original circle.

Comment: @DavidK: I wanted to make a similar comment, that there are at least two solutions - the 3 circles inside, or the 3 circles outside the original circle...

Comment: @virolino For congruent, distinct circles, yes. If the circles can be non-congruent then we can make all four circles tangent at one point and then we can have one or two inside the original circle and the others outside.

Comment: Consider this an exercise in how to specify a problem so that you get the kind of solution you want. The problem as stated is grievously underconstrained relative to the kind of solution you want. One solution method is just to draw a single line through the center $O$ of the original circle, choose one intersection $P$ of that line and the circle to be the point of tangency; choose any three distinct points on that line other than $O$ and $P$; construct circles through $P$ with each of those three points as center. You can continue constructing as many more such circles as you like.

Comment: @DavidK: you are so true! I did not even notice that, thank you. Indeed, the problem is quite under-defined. Not only there are at least two solution, but at least 2 classes of different solutions. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now draw circles $\omega_p, \omega_q, \omega_q$ with centers $p, q, r$ respectively, each tangent to $\bigcirc O$ at $P,Q,R$ respectively.

I would mention why the circles actually are tangent to $\bigcirc O$. This is simple, but worth justifying. If nothing else, it checks the requirement off the list, and makes sure it's not read as an assumption or something to be proved later.

I would replace the second paragraph with just "Construct $\omega_p$ as the [incircle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incircle_and_excircles) of $\triangle ABO$, $\omega_q$ as the incircle of $\triangle BCO$, and $\omega_r$ as the incircle of $\triangle CAO$."

Constructing a triangle's incircle is a standard construction, and readers familiar with compass-and-straightedge construction will know that it's normally done using angle bisectors, or at least will know that it can be done. If this is in the context of a book or class, you can refer back to some previous construction or exercise. If you think it's absolutely necessary, describe constructing a general triangle's incircle as a lemma here, rather than describing the steps three times.

Proving the four circles actually are mutually tangent will require naming some of the points and lines omitted there, but only the ones you need for this.

Comment: Yes, naming these as incircles not only shortens the exposition, but it increases the clarity.  It answers _What is special about $\omega_p$?_ It's the incircle of $\triangle AOB$.

Comment: I rewrote the solution based on your recommendation.  Can you take a look and provide any feedback?

Comment: Looks good. (mininum comment length here)

Answer (score 2):

Alternate construction of congruent circles within the given circle:

Line $OA$ intersects circle $O$ at points $A$ and $B$. Circle with center $A$ passing through point $O$ intersects circle $O$ at points $C$ and $D$, and line $OA$ at point $E$. Circle with center $E$ passing through points $C$ and $D$ intersects line $OA$ at point $F$. The line perpendicular to $OA$ at $F$ intersects segments $OC$ and $OD$ at points $G$ and $H$. Circle with center $O$ passing through points $G$ and $H$ intersects line $OA$ at point $I$. Points $G$, $H$ and $I$ are the centers of the desired circles tangent to circle $O$ at points $C$, $D$ and $B$ respectively.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Descartes kissing circles relation connecting 4 curvatures
$1/R_i :$

$$  (1/R_1+ 1/R_2 +1/R_3+ 1/R_4)^2= 2(1/R_1^2+ 1/R_2^2 +1/R_3^2+ 1/R_4^2)=  $$

The curvatures are positive for external contact, negative for internal contact, including zero for straight line special cases.

[Touching circles](https://www.google.com/search?q=kissing%20circles%20problem&oq=&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUqCQgAECMYJxjqAjIJCAAQIxgnGOoCMgkIARAjGCcY6gIyCQgCECMYJxjqAjIJCAMQIxgnGOoCMgkIBBAjGCcY6gIyCQgFECMYJxjqAjIJCAYQIxgnGOoCMgkIBxAjGCcY6gLSAQkxNjg0ajBqMTWoAgiwAgE&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#fpstate=ive&vld=cid:015e565d,vid:BmJznF7Wlnw,st:0)

Answer (score 0):

I have another potential way of constructing the three circles.

Let's take $O$ the center of the first circle $C_1$.

Take one radius $[OA]$.

Construct the point $B$ middle of $[OA]$.

Construct the circle $C_2$ of center $B$ and of radius $[BA]$.

Rince and repeat two other times.

You will have four circles, all tangent to each other in point $A$.